# Amchart : show legends for specific series only

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have a graph that mixes column and line charts. I would like to display the legend only for the column chart.

My full code is available here: https://codepen.io/European-DataLab/pen/wVJKrN?editors=0010

Here, is the code for the legend :

```
// Legend settings
series.name = "Période référence";
series2.name = "Cotisation minimale";
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.position = "top";
chart.legend.align = "center";
```

In my example,  the legend for the two lines is shown. Here is my output: [image]

However, I would like to have this output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be setting the hiddenInLegend  property to true

```
series.hiddenInLegend = true;
```

This should work as per the documentation below

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#hiddenInLegend_property